# VBA to check the number of Data Points in a Sparkline

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro which is running comparisons between two files and creating a validation file which lists if the numbers either match or don't match between the two files. 
I was wondering is there anyway to for VBA to calculate the amount of datapoints in a sparkline?
My sparklines should always have 12 data points, which exist on another tab.

I don't have any code examples as I don't even know where to begin with this.
I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: You just need to count the data points of the range (in a sheet) that is the source of that sparkline isn't it? It's not very clear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: No, there have been times that the data range has been correct but the sparkline has not updated correctly. I want to specifically count how many points are being displayed in the sparkline

Comment: If you set the data source range for your sparkline e.g `A1:B12` once, it should *always* update correctly if you change the values in that range. If not you should find your error in your process and fix it. A workaround counting any points would be a bad practice anyway even if this was possible.

Comment: It sometimes doesn't work depending on how the data sources are updated. Eg cutting has a different effect to deleting a row. This isn't a work around this is a safety check. At the moment somebody actually manually looks at 12 different sparklines to make sure they have updated correctly from the previous week. If I could have my macro check if there are 12 data points in them then that would be of benefit to us

Comment: My approach would be to ensure (eg with sheet protection) that in the source range nobody can delete/move/insert rows but just edit values. Or a script that just sets the correct source range for your sparklines no matter if they're right or wrong before. This way you don't need to perform any fancy test but ensure that everything is correct.

Comment: I actually hadn't thought of the first option, I had thought of the second and may implement something like that for the future. However this check may still be needed. Basically it's a report for management and it's insisted upon that there be checks, so if I can have what I want here (Even though it's unusual) it would be appreciated.

Comment: The issue is your question is a bit too broad to give full answer. But to give you a hint where to start: `Debug.Print ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count` would print out the number of points used in the first data row of the active chart. Try to write some code (looping through all charts within the sheet `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects`) and if you got stuck come back with a specific question to your code.

Comment: Thanks for that, if a sparkline is in A3, is it possible to output to say E3 the amount of data points?

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand what you mean with sparkline. I misunderstood because I needed to translate it into german, I'm not native English so I thought you were talking about an ordinary chart object.

**Now to real sparklines**
There is no possibility to count the data points directly. The only thing you can do is validate the data source, and see how big it is (how many cells):

```
Public Sub CountSparklineDataPoints()
    Dim oSparkGroup As SparklineGroup

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each oSparkGroup In ActiveSheet.Columns("A").SparklineGroups 'all sparklines in column A are processed
            .Range(oSparkGroup.Item(1).Location.Address).Offset(0, 4) = .Range(oSparkGroup.Item(1).SourceData).Cells.Count
            'write 4 columns right of the sparkline                   = the count of the cells in sourcedata
        Next oSparkGroup
    End With
End Sub
```

*Note this counts also empty cells that are included in the SourceData. So this is a proof if the SourceData size is correct.*

---

For external addresses this would be a bit more extensive:

```
Public Sub CountSparklineDataPoints()
    Dim oSparkGroup As SparklineGroup

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each oSparkGroup In ActiveSheet.Columns("E").SparklineGroups 'all sparklines in column A are processed
            .Range(oSparkGroup.Item(1).Location.Address).Offset(0, 4) = RangeFromAddress(oSparkGroup.Item(1).SourceData).Cells.Count
            'write 4 columns right of the sparkline                   = the count of the cells in sourcedata
        Next oSparkGroup
    End With
End Sub


'================================
' VBA Get Range from address string
'
' http://www.exceltoolset.com
'================================
Function RangeFromAddress( _
 ByRef Address As String, _
 Optional obj As Object) As Range
    Dim Wb As Workbook, FallbackWb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet, FallbackSh As Worksheet
    Dim w, s, a As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim n As Name

    On Error Resume Next

    Set n = Names(Address)
    If Not (n Is Nothing) Then
        Set RangeFromAddress = n.RefersToRange
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not (obj Is Nothing) Then
        Set FallbackWb = GetObjectParentWorkbook(obj)
        Set FallbackSh = GetObjectParentSheet(obj)
    Else
        Set FallbackWb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set FallbackSh = ActiveSheet
    End If

    i = InStr(Address, "!")
    If i = 0 Then
        Set RangeFromAddress = FallbackSh.Range(Address)
    Else
        s = Left$(Address, i - 1)
        a = Mid$(Address, i + 1)
        If InStr(s, "'") = 1 Then
            s = Mid$(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)
        End If

        i = 1
        Do Until i > Len(s)
            If Mid$(s, i, 2) = "''" Then
                s = Left$(s, i - 1) & Mid$(s, i + 1)
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        i = InStr(s, "]")
        If i = 0 Then
            Set sh = FallbackWb.Sheets(s)
        Else
            w = Left$(s, i - 1)
            j = InStr(w, "[")
            If j <> 0 Then w = Left$(w, j - 1) & Mid$(w, j + 1)
            s = Mid$(s, i + 1)

            Set Wb = Workbooks(w)
            If Wb Is Nothing Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=w, Notify:=True)
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
            Set sh = Wb.Sheets(s)
        End If
        Set RangeFromAddress = sh.Range(a)
    End If
End Function

Function GetObjectParentWorkbook(aObject As Object) As Workbook
    Dim o As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

    If aObject Is Nothing Then GoTo ErrorExit
    Set o = aObject.Parent

    If TypeOf aObject Is Workbook Then
        Set GetObjectParentWorkbook = aObject
        GoTo ErrorExit
    End If

    Do Until (TypeOf o Is Workbook) Or (TypeOf o Is Application)
        Set o = o.Parent
    Loop

    If TypeOf o Is Workbook Then Set GetObjectParentWorkbook = o

ErrorExit:
    Exit Function

ErrorHandle:
    Resume ErrorExit
End Function

Function GetObjectParentSheet(aObject As Object) As Object
    Dim op As Object
    On Error Resume Next

    If aObject Is Nothing Then GoTo ErrorExit
    Set op = aObject.Parent
    If op Is Nothing Then GoTo ErrorExit

    If TypeOf op Is Workbook Then
        Set GetObjectParentSheet = aObject
        GoTo ErrorExit
    End If

    Do Until (TypeOf op Is Worksheet) Or (TypeOf op Is Application)
        Set op = op.Parent
    Loop

    If TypeOf op Is Worksheet Then Set GetObjectParentSheet = op

ErrorExit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I am getting an error with your code. Application defined or object defined error. I have my data points on a different tab. do I need to put that into the code?

Comment: That's quite cumbersome for external addresses to get their range. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, however that is still not running for me. I'm not sure if I am running it correctly, should I have all this code stored in a module and just run the macro?

Comment: Of course you need to change `ActiveSheet.Columns("E")` to the column where your sparklines are, or into `ActiveSheet.Cells` for every cell in the sheet.

Comment: This code is tested and worked for me. And "*didn't work*" is no valid error description as you can imagine. That's like when you say "*my car doesn't work*", the issue can be anything from empty gas to broken motor or stolen wheels. So if you expect help you must be as detailed as possible in your description. At least error message and position of occurrence is essential, more is better. Put in some effort!

Comment: Yes the code is running yet nothing appears to happen. I don't see any count of data points appearing. I also don't see any error message so cannot include this? My message was initially asking was I running it correctly as I was worried was there an error with my method of running it. Considering you have provided this code, and I can't understand how it is working then I cannot provide much more detail. If I was a passenger in a broken down car and I had no knowledge of what had happened then I would have to say didn't work. Nobody is making you respond here.

Comment: even the info that there is *no* error message is a useful information. Make sure `Worksheets("Sheet1")` is the correct worksheet name and `ActiveSheet.Columns("E")` where your sparklines are. You might change that to `Worksheets("SomeOtherWorksheet").Columns("E")`. Then run `CountSparklineDataPoints` in step-by-step mode to debug it (you should be familiar with basic debugging) and see e.g. if the `each` loop is run. I cannot debug it from remote so you need to try to find out some details.